# Brush multiple cells foreground within a GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, converters

I want to reuse a cell style for multiple GridViews in my application in a financial context. That means all cells with less than 0 should have a foreground color of red and all more than 0 should be green and 0 values should be black.
So I wrote the following:

```
public class FinancialConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is decimal d)
        {
            if (d > 0)
            {
                return Brushes.Green;
            }

            if (d < 0)
            {
                return Brushes.Red;
            }
        }

        return Brushes.Black;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My problem is now, how can I apply this in a more generic way?

```
    <local:FinancialConverter x:Key="FinancialConverter" />        
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="GridViewCellStyle0">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Change1Year,Converter={StaticResource FinancialConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="GridViewCellStyle00">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Change3Year,Converter={StaticResource FinancialConverter}}"/>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Trends}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Change1Year,StringFormat=p}" CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCellStyle0}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Change3Year,StringFormat=p}" CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCellStyle00}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I just want to create one GridViewCellStyle making the convert on the actual value.

I found a solution like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvData" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Content.Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource Conv}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

The problem is that the string value of the Content.Text is a percentage value in my case and I would like to get the underlying (binded) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom column type and create the cell style dynamically:

```
public class FinancialTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    private static readonly FinancialConverter _converter = new FinancialConverter();

    public override BindingBase Binding
    {
        get { return base.Binding; }
        set
        {
            base.Binding = value;
            //generate the cell template:
            Binding binding = base.Binding as Binding;
            if (binding != null && binding.Path != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(binding.Path.Path))
                CellStyle = CreateCellStyle(binding.Path.Path);
        }
    }

    private static Style CreateCellStyle(string sourceProperty)
    {
        Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.ForegroundProperty, new Binding(sourceProperty) { Converter = _converter }));
        return style;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <local:FinancialTextColumn Binding="{Binding Change1Year}" />
    <local:FinancialTextColumn Binding="{Binding Change3Year}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

You can't do this in pure XAML because there is no way to reuse all but the binding path of a Style.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much.